# Configuring Kafka with jmx-exporter in windows

Tags: java, windows, apache-kafka, jmx, prometheus

I am trying to start configure kafka with JMX in windows but by adding `KAFKA_OPTS` not working in windows. Trying below `.bat`. Any idea why I am not able to start kafka with JMX exporter?

```
SET KAFKA_HOME=D:\Pratyush\kafka\kafka_2.12-2.1.0
SET KAFKA_OPTS=-javaagent:%KAFKA_HOME%\KafkaMonitor\jmx_prometheus_javaagent- 
                0.11.0.jar=7071:%KAFKA_HOME%\kafka-0-8-2.yml

cd %KAFKA_HOME%\bin\windows

kafka-server-start.bat %KAFKA_HOME%\config\server.properties
```

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: what is the error message?